# PHP repetitive function call, best practice?

Tags: php, javascript, cron

I am looking to create a php script that checks a website to see if there is certain content on it, and then text me if the content is there. After some reasearch, I found [PHP DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) which I will use to load the html, parse it, and then check if the given content is there. However, this can only happen each time I load the page. I want this script to run like every 30 min or so. What would be the best way of doing this?

Solutions I have come across:

I read that I could use cron jobs, although I have also read that running repeated function calls on a server like this is bad practice. I also thought that I could use javascript's setTimeout to refresh the page at a certain interval. However, using this method, my computer has to be on with a browser window open. I would prefer if this were not the case.

Comment: A cron job would work just fine for what you're trying to do.

Comment: Cron is the best option.

Comment: Have you thought about cron :-)

Comment: Upvotes!  Upvotes all around!

Comment: "*I have also read that running repeated function calls on a server like this is bad practice*" that's what a web server does, every visitor more calls, how can this be bad?

Comment: @dagon Just out of curiosity, if I wanted to offer this to a bunch of people, is a cron job still the way to go? Wouldn't that be pretty crushing on my server? In that case, would I want to opt for the client side & do javascript?

Comment: Unless your clients have their own web server to run the PHP script, then it will have to be done on yours.

Comment: Favorited just for the cron comments :-)

Comment: Cron job is more than enough [I upvoted to make all even]

Comment: what is your server a 286? you are worrying about nothing here.

Comment: @dagon What if I changed it to every 5min? Would you still say cron jobs?

Comment: yes i would, a moderately busy web-server is hit several hundred times a minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HA ! cron job, unless your using a very poor server it will handle the load fine, but not knowing the exact scrip, i could be wrong on this!.

If its a shared host, check what rules they have on using cron

Comment: this question has entered the twilight zone.

Answer (score 1):

If you want something to be executed every 30 minutes, then cron jobs are the way to go. (creds go to @Matt, @Sven, @wanovak, @Dagon)

Comment: no, you've just misunderstood the point of comments, they don't exist for you to give solutions, answers are for that: http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment

Comment: sure, that's why you posted every one else's comments as an answer ;-), so noble of you.

Comment: @dagon Just sayin that if you post it, I'll accept it for all your generosity.

Comment: +1 because now I can +1 all the "use cron" comments with 4 fewer clicks. Call me lazy ...